# How to host a static website with authentication?

Tags: html, r, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I want to host a static website and restrict the access to those .html pages (excluding the login.html) with some user authentication. When the user has got registered and received a custom claim (from me) he should be able to read/visit the other .html pages.

I started with Firebase but all i could do there was to set up the authentification and store all my data in the Firestore / Real time database. Since i am generating the html with some R code (and the bookdown package) i want to upload the full html file and restrict the access to the file itself. Otherwise i would have to store the whole content in the Firestore which would be cumbersome.

Since i am a beginner i have no idea if this is realistic. Is there a possibility to do that in an easy and low-cost way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: All files stored on Firebase Hosting are readable to everyone worldwide. There is no way to limit access to those files. If your use-case requires that you can limit access to the hosted files, you'll want to use a different hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see that it is not possible with Firebase, thats why i actually asked if there is a possibility to do that. Maybe my question was not that clear, I don't have to stick with Firebase, i just started with it until i realized that it is not possible with it. So do you know any hosting provider where i can limit the access to a hosted file or do you think it is just not possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but recommending technologies is off-topic on Stack Overflow. That said, if you search for hosting providers, you're bound to find a lot of them.